# Ag-Grid add cell styles after grid rendered

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to implement a custom color formater in ag-grid where users can select a color from the color picker and change cell background color or font color..

I am able to get the column Def but not able to implement the changes in Ag-grid.

I have been trying:

```
this.data.columnApi.getColumn(index).getColDef().cellStyle['color'] = 'red';
this.data.gridApi.refreshCells();
and also
this.data.gridApi.redrawRows();
```

Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: could you provide a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksc8sk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code and replacing

```
  this.gridApi.refreshCells({
        columns: ["make"]
      });
```

with

```
  this.gridApi.redrawRows();
```

worked for me giving the correct output